# React Material UI Visual Editor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm starting an open source project, a visual editor for React Material UI.

This is the [link](https://github.com/DarkArtistry/open-react-material-ui) to the project.

Users will be able to drag and drop material components on the left drawer to the dropzone (middle/user layout), and use the toolbox on the right drawer to edit the CSS of individual components in the dropzone. Finally with a click of the button, the platform will generate react/ react-material-ui code and also have the capability convert the xml structure to a json for various device purposes.

This project is at the very beginning phase where I only have 1 button component.

Before diving deeper I would like to understand if my current implementations are valid or if there are better ways to implement this.

Particularly:

When I handle drag start:

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.currentTarget.innerHTML);
```

and when I handle drop:

```
ev.preventDefault();
ev.stopPropagation();
let html = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
ev.currentTarget.style.border = "none";
let text = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
let element = document.getElementById(text)
let element_prime = element.cloneNode(true)
ev.currentTarget.append(element_prime)
```

The reason why I feel uncomfortable is because I'm actually using the document queries, which is not exactly the "react way" of doing things.

I'm thinking of only using `createRef()` when selecting a component in the dropzone when working on the CSS in the toolbox area.

[link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to createRef()

I generate the ids of the components with:

```
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
```

Comment: I made a similar concept last year I would recommend you to take a look on React-Dnd or Dnd-kit libraries which can help you about drag&drop utility functions. Also I would recommend you to define your phases up front. I added cms like editing, nested drag&drop, css config, select&hover box and options, publishing or exporting etc. Depends on those requirement project can become very complicated and easy to lose context. You will definitely learn lots of thing on this project but plan first then execute that would be my best advice for you.

Comment: @tunaayberk thank you for the advice! i will look at the recommended libraries ! Exactly, so i'm taking a pause in my execution and i'm trying to read more before i continue.

Comment: @tunaayberk i've checked the codes of react-dnd and i think it's pretty hard to maintain if i would focus on the working on the react way and as the versions updates for react. i think i will work with the document queries as the performance do not make much difference and it is more future proof. Having said that i gain some ideas from how he manages the hover! So Thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

######## UPDATE - 26 Apr 2022 ########
Based on some work done and relooking into the comments by @tunaayberk I found a way to gracefully handle it the react way. So react-dnd does make use of the redux flow and it has its own provider. An even better way to form the hierarchical json tree is to actually store it in the global state and just rendering the components in the dropzone from the json tree. That way we do away with handling the MUI classnames, DOM nested targets etc. Graceful way to handle this project using the react way.

checkout my medium post and give it some claps: https://medium.com/@kenneth.gzhao/react-material-ui-visual-editor-d1949262bce4